Issue with creating nodes from CSV using Migrate Plus module
I am encountering an issue while attempting to create nodes from a CSV file using the Migrate Plus module in Drupal 10.2. The nodes are successfully created with most fields populated from the CSV, but I am facing an error specifically related to a taxonomy reference field named 'field_product_materials'. This field is configured to reference the 'Materials' vocabulary (machine name: materials). But when I check Terms in the vocabulary the first term in csv 'Material 1' is created. SO only the issue seems to be term attaching to node.
Error:
I am receiving the following error during the import:
TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /var/www/html/docroot/modules/contrib/entity_reference_revisions/src/Plugin/DataType/EntityReferenceRevisions.php on line 117 #0
/var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldItemBase.php(139): Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\Plugin\DataType\EntityReferenceRevisions->setValue()
CSV Data:
ArticleNumber,ArticleName,SizeFilter,SizeAttribute,Material,Specifications
RAND001,Artical Name 1,DFS1,4.6,Material 1,"Some HTML Content 1"
RAND002,Artical Name 2,DFS2,4.5,Material 2,"Some HTML Content 2"
RAND003,Artical Name 3,DFS1,4.6,Material 3,"Some HTML Content 3"
RAND004,Artical Name 4,DFS1,4.6,Material 4,"Some HTML Content 4"

Migration Configuration:
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: product_kits
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: products
label: 'Import product Kits'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: /home/data/data.csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - ArticleNumber

process:

  title: ArticleName
  field_migration_unique_id: ArticleNumber
  field_size_attribute: SizeAttribute
  field_size_filter: SizeFilter
  body:
    -
      plugin: callback

      callable: utf8_encode

      source: Specifications

  field_product_materials:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: Material
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle: materials  #VOCABULARY_MACHINE_NAME
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: product_kit

migration_dependencies: null

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue. Thank you!

It's the contributed entity_reference_revisions module with the type error. A stack trace would be helpful.

entity_reference_revisions usually refers to paragraphs, not taxonomy. Are you sure you are correctly diagnosing the issue?

Thanks @jaypan for your help. Got your point . It sould be reference not refrerence revision. It fixes the issue.

Great. You should post that as an answer to the thread.
